# forward all emails to gmail email /etc/aliases

Tags: aliases

I want to forward all emails to my gmail email address.

In my aliases file. I have this code:

```
sales: myemail@gmail.com
```

and it's working fine,but I have a hundreds of email addresses, I can not add them all manually I am trying this code:

```
*: myemail@gmail.com
```

but it is not working:

So, how I can tell the software to forward my all emails to the gmail email?

I've got exim installed without cpanel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is possible, it will be interpreted as a literal string. You will need to add a new router to exim

```
catchall_pub:
  driver = redirect
  domains = yourdomain
  data = youremail@gmail.com
```

Comment: Thank you very much .. but what if i want forward them to a file? i get this error -> pipe_transport unset in catchall_pub router <br /> I am using ( data = |/home/resend.php )

Comment: i've added this lines in the config   file_transport = address_file
pipe_transport = address_pipe

it's now working so fine, thank you very much Lucas

Comment: did you selected the name of the router randomly or it should be as that? .. can i change the name? or can i create my own routers? How can i read more about this? do you have a useful links ?
Thanks bro

Comment: You can create your own routers, the name is random. You can learn more by searching for it in google or going to the exim website and read their documentation.